# Undefined value from Object Literal (switch replacement)

Tags: javascript

So, I'm a javascript n00b. Have heard that case/switch statements are...passé. I'm trying to wrap my head around object literals as their replacement structure.

After searching and trying various iterations in my code, I still cannot figure out why the "switch" variable value is coming back as "undefined". In my limited experience, a variable with a value of "undefined" usually means that it has no value, right? Is it a variable scope issue?

From what I gather the code is doing is creating a object (mod). The mod object has properties with the name of [3-18]. Each of these properties have values which are functions. These functions return a string value.

Here's what I've got so far:

```
    function getModValue(str) {
    var search = str;
    var mod = {
        3: function() {return "-3";},
        4: function() {return "-2";},
        5: function() {return "-2";},
        6: function() {return "-1";},
        7: function() {return "-1";},
        8: function() {return "-1";},
        9: function() {return "0";},
        10: function() {return "0";},
        11: function() {return "0";},
        12: function() {return "0";},
        13: function() {return "+1";},
        14: function() {return "+1";},
        15: function() {return "+1";},
        16: function() {return "+2";},
        17: function() {return "+2";},
        18: function() {return "+3";}
    }
    mod[search]();
    }

    alert(getModValue("14"));
```

Here is my (non)working example: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QGL2S/)

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is just you forgot the `return` at the end.

I think you are overengineering. This works and it's much more simple:

```
function getModValue(str) {
    var mod = {
        3:  "-3",
        5:  "-2",
        4:  "-2",
        6:  "-1",
        7:  "-1",
        8:  "-1",
        9:  "0",
        10: "0",
        11: "0",
        12: "0",
        13: "+1",
        14: "+1",
        15: "+1",
        16: "+2",
        17: "+2",
        18: "+3"
    }
    return mod[str];
    }

alert(getModValue("14"));
```

PS: Checking a 3d6 roll?

UPDATE: Think that `mod` is a map, where the keys are numbers and the values are strings. When you look for a value using the key, Javascript has to compare your key with the existing ones. Check the following:

```
var number="1";
number==1 //true, because it's like if '==' makes a "toString()"
number===1 //false

var myObj={hello: function(){ return "Hello";}};
myObj.hello();
myObj["hello"](); // equivalent
```

Comment: You get the accepted answer for two reasons: 1) you helped clean-up my  unnecessary code, 2) guessing the purpose of the function. One further question. Why do we not have to declare the switch value in quotes? getModValue(str) takes in a string and returns a string.

Answer (score 1):

```js
const responseToParse = {
  3: '-3',
  4: '-2',
  5: '-2',
  6: '-1',
  7: '-1',
  8: '-1',
  9: '0',
  10: '0',
  11: '0',
  12: '0',
  13: '+1',
  14: '+1',
  15: '+1',
  16: '+2',
  17: '+2',
  18: '+3',
  19: undefined,
  20: null
}

const MyObjectLiteralLibrary = {
  3: response => response[3],
  4: response => response[4],
  5: response => response[5],
  6: response => response[6],
  7: response => response[7],
  8: response => response[8],
  9: response => response[9],
  10: response => response[10],
  11: response => response[11],
  12: response => response[12],
  13: response => response[13],
  14: response => response[14],
  15: response => response[15],
  16: response => response[16],
  17: response => response[17],
  18: response => response[18],
  19: response => response[19],
  20: response => response[20]
}
let str
str = 14
console.log(MyObjectLiteralLibrary[str](responseToParse))

str = 19
console.log(MyObjectLiteralLibrary[str](responseToParse))

str = 20
console.log(MyObjectLiteralLibrary[str](responseToParse))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Nice one; Yes, object literals are better than a switch when some of the cases returning an undefined or a specific cases only. This can be done through switch but will leave a fall-through in many cases.

I played around and came up with this logic in ES6 format. Please look into the code snippet above if that helps.

You can loop over defaultList of cases or a set of required cases. Also, If you want to parse a JSON object this is very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You have missed return on last line of your api.
 **return** modsearch;